# Problem deleting documents using GridFSBucket in MongoDB with Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I'm working on a **Node.js** script where I'm using **MongoDB** as my database. I'm using **GridFSBucket** to handle documents in my database from **mongodb library**. I have three tables for that: `document`, `document.chunks`, and `document.files`.

I'm trying to delete specific documents using the bucket.delete(document._id) method, but I'm encountering an error that says: `MongoRuntimeError: File not found for id`

Here is the code I'm using:

```
const bucket = new GridFSBucket(db, { bucketName: "document" });
await bucket.delete(document._id);
```

I've confirmed that the document does exist in the database by using the findOne method from MongoDB, and it successfully retrieves the document. Here is the code I used:

```
const doc = await db.collection("document").findOne({
    _id: document._id,
});
```

This code works as expected and returns the correct document. However, when I try to delete the same document using the bucket.delete(document._id) method, it still throws the `MongoRuntimeError: File not found for id`

Has anyone experienced this problem before or have any idea how I can resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Configuration:**

1. MongoDB: MongoDB 3.6.23 Community
2. Database options:

> ```
>  {
>   enableUtf8Validation: true,
>   forceServerObjectId: false,
>   pkFactory: { createPk: [Function: createPk] },
>   raw: false,
>   readPreference: ReadPreference {
>     mode: 'primary',
>     tags: undefined,
>     hedge: undefined,
>     maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
>     minWireVersion: undefined
>   },
>   retryWrites: true
> }
> ```

1. Database read preference

> ```
>  {
>   mode: 'primary',
>   tags: undefined,
>   hedge: undefined,
>   maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
>   minWireVersion: undefined
> }
> ```

2. Dependencies

> ```
>   {
>     "mongodb": "^6.3.0",
>     "@types/node": "^20.11.16",
>     "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
>     "tslib": "^2.6.2",
>     "uuid": "^9.0.1"
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to delete files through GridFS but instead of using the document identifier of the *"document"* collection as a parameter of the *"delete"* function I have had to first do a search in the bucket by *filename* and then also delete the document from the document table.

```
  const bucket = new GridFSBucket(db, { bucketName: "document" });
  const bucketFile = await bucket
    .find({
      filename: {
        $regex: `^${document._id.toString()}`,
      },
    })
    .toArray();

const bucketFileId = bucketFile[0]._id;
  await bucket.delete(bucketFileId); //THIS DELETE DOCUMENTS FROM document.chunks COLLECTION AND DOCUMENT document.files COLLECTION
  const deleteResult = await db
    .collection("document")
    .deleteOne({ _id: document._id }); //THIS DELETE DOCUMENT FROM document COLLECTION
```